# Powershell EWS Search filter NOT

Tags: powershell, exchangewebservices

i've a tool designed un powershell for parse emails using EWS, however i would like to exclude emails that have specific content in Subject. unfortunately i don't know how to build the NOT condition, example:

```
New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter.Not+ConstainsSubstring([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessageSchema]::Subject, "Text To Match and Exclude")
```

Does anyone knows how to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$SearchFilterContainsSubString = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+ContainsSubstring(
[Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemSchema]::Subject, "Text To Match and Exclude")
$SearchFilterNot = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+Not($SearchFilterContainsSubString)
```

Comment: Worked! much appreciated :)